# is application.xml file must to run a spring mvc application in tomcat 7?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC.

I've downloaded one application and trying to deploy it using Apache Tomcat, but unable to run it.

I'm getting this error message:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /GeekNews could not be started

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

error logs

```
J
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibLocationRule.begin(WebRuleSet.java:1274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    Jun 23, 2014 11:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/GeekNews] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jun 23, 2014 11:21:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software     Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\sample.war

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: taglib definition not consistent with specification version

    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig parseWebXml
    SEVERE: Occurred at line 33 column 11
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
    SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
    J    un 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is     already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is     already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is     already defined
        Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is     already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
    J    un 23, 2014 11:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
        SEVERE: Error getConfigured
    Jun 23, 2014 11:22:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
    SEVERE: Context [/GeekNews] startup failed due to previous errors
    Jun 23, 2014 11:23:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 23, 2014 11:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Jun 23, 2014 11:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jun 23, 2014 11:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Jun 23, 2014 11:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
    INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

What to do to run this application? Is `geeknews.xml` file required to run it? `(conf/Cata*/localhost)`

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `application.xml` is part of the problem while looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Why did you repost the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372506/unable-to-run-the-spring-mvc-program.

Comment: Bart- i am just asking is it required 100% for a spring proj?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have libraries conflicts; the error is saying that you are using some taglibs whom version is not compatible with specification (JSP and Servlet specification)

I raccomend to you to check your libs....it doesn't seem something related to spring